# How do I change the frame size?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, transforms, image, scene

I've been trying to make a camera view more of this room for my scene.

To specify, I don't want to change the FOV. I can't zoom out by moving the camera further because there are walls behind it, and no matter what I do in the aspect settings, it doesn't fit the intended view.

[image: Camera supposed to view everything seen out of the frame.]

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time the camera's clipping values are generating problems for people because they are wondering why something disappears in their scene. This is a good example where it makes sense to use it for:

Let's say you have a certain focal length for the camera that you want to keep. But to capture everything you want in the picture, you have to go outside the room's walls. This looks a bit like that:

[image: camera outside]

That's because of the default value of *Clip Start* = 0.1 in the camera's clipping settings. This makes things disappear when the camera gets very close. If you now play around with the start value and increase it to something like 2 m, everything that's closer (like the outside walls) will be invisible in camera but still contribute to everything in the scene, reflect light, be visible in reflections or mirrors and even reappear for the camera if you move further away, without having to change anything.

[image: looking in]

Comment: +1 very good! i just realized that's where i could use clipping distance, learned something new :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Actually I always worked with backface culling or making walls invisible for the camera in the past when working on my own home. But just a few months ago when I worked on it again for the first time in years, I realized that clipping is really useful for that.

Answer (score 5):

You could make your Wall that is blocking the camera a separate object and then uncheck the "camera" setting in the visibility tab. This way you still get the lighting effects of bounce light but its invisible.

Just make sure, to seperate the back wall from the front wall by going into the edit mode and selecting the part that has to be seperated and pressing P

[image]

Comment: @TheLabCat Making it a separate object and invisible is not even necessary...

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement the [Dolly Zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom) effect to capture more of the scene while your near field plane of the camera is still in the same position. This entails increasing the Field of View (FOV) but at the same time moving the camera's position foward until it's near field plane is in the same location again as before the FOV adjustment.

[image]

You can also make the walls invisible from it's back (assuming your face normals are pointing into the room) if you select those walls and enable *Backface Culling* under *Material Properties > Settings > Backface Culling*. That way you can move your camera further back and not see the walls as they become invisible.